# How to get the checked value of radio button when container is visible using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 3 div like below each with 2 radio buttons in each div. I am trying to get the value of the checked radio button in the div that is showing *ie*. has `display: block`.

```
<div class="details" style="display: none;">
<input id="r1" name="room" type="radio" value="1">
<input id="r2" name="room" checked type="radio" value="2">
</div>

<div class="details" style="display: block;">
<input id="t1" name="room1"checked  type="radio" value="3">
<input id="t2" name="room1" type="radio" value="4">
</div>
```

I know how to use

```
$('.details').css('display') == 'block')
```

but having trouble combining it with

```
$('input[name=???]:radio:checked').attr('value')
```

Does anyone know how I can get the checked value from the visible div only?

Comment: the questions are: you want to get values to submit them ? you want to get and sort values on change ? or ?

Comment: sorry, I want to get the checked value (also if it changed) and then use it like var xxxxxx = THERADIOVALUE

Answer (score 0):

Use [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```js
let v = $('.details:visible').find('input:radio:checked').val()
console.log('This is visible checked radio value: ' + v)

$('.details input:radio').change(function(){
  let v = $(this).val();
  console.log('This is clicked radio value: ' + v)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="details" style="display: none;">
  <input id="r1" name="room" type="radio" value="1">
  <input id="r2" name="room" checked type="radio" value="2">
</div>

<div class="details" style="display: block;">
  <input id="t1" name="room1" checked type="radio" value="3">
  <input id="t2" name="room1" type="radio" value="4">
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant - will this work if the user clicks a different radio button within the visible div

Comment: @bobbit You want if you click on `radio` get `value` too?

Comment: yes if they choose the other radio button not pre selected, get that value - like the one with value of 4 tks

Comment: amazing tks - i have a slight problem - I have a function which assigns the display block or display none to the divs. On the page it writes display: block; against the div i want to show, but the source code says display: none - the function doesnt work because i think it sees the visible div as not visible, any ideas - i get value undefined

Comment: @bobbit I think you need to create a new question. this topic is solved, please +1 if you like, and check as accepted, then make a new question, I going to help you over, be sure, to share your related code over.

Comment: posted new question